# time on xaxis in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have my x-axis values in this format : `['May 23 2018 06:31:52 GMT', 'May 23 2018 06:32:02 GMT', 'May 23 2018 06:32:12 GMT', 'May 23 2018 06:32:22 GMT', 'May 23 2018 06:32:32 GMT']`
and corresponding values for the y-axis which are some numbers.
But when I am plotting these using plotly , x-axis show only part of the date (May 23 2018) for each point. Time for each point is not shown.

I tried setting up tickformat also in layout, but it does not seems to work.

```
            layout = go.Layout(
                title=field+ "_its diff_value chart",
                xaxis = dict(
                    tickformat = '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S'
                )
            )
```

any help is appreciated.

This is the screenshot of the graph made.

[image]

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 4):

- Try converting your x-values to `datetime` objects
- Then tell plotly to use a fixed tick distance

[image]

```
import random
import datetime
import plotly

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

x = [datetime.datetime.now()]
for d in range(100):
    x.append(x[0] + datetime.timedelta(d))
y = [random.random() for _ in x]

scatter = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=x, y=y)
layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(xaxis={'type': 'date', 
                                         'tick0': x[0], 
                                         'tickmode': 'linear', 
                                         'dtick': 86400000.0 * 14}) # 14 days
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=[scatter], layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip inconsistent time series, add this before plotting the plotly chart

```
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=['2018-05-23 06:31:52','2018-05-23 06:32:02']), 
        dict(bounds=['2018-05-23 06:32:02','2018-05-23 06:32:12']),
        dict(bounds=['2018-05-23 06:32:12','2018-05-23 06:32:22']),
        dict(bounds=['2018-05-23 06:32:22','2018-05-23 06:32:32'])  
    ]
)
```